# Constructing Cayley tables and generating groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Given two permutations $a=(123)(45)$ and $b=(12)(3)(4)(5)$ generate a group $(G,*)$ of order $12$ and construct a Cayley table.

The bit I’m stuck on is how you generate the group, once I’ve done that I believe I can construct the table

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The group generated by a and b consists of all distinct "words" formed out of a and b.  Exhibit twelve distinct words.

Note that $ab=(13)(45)$, so $(ab)^2=e$.

There are at most twelve, because $ab=b^{-1}a^{-1}, a^6=b^2=e$ implies that every word can be written in the form $a^jb^i\,,1\le j\le6, 1\le i\le2$.